# Multi word replacement within xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, replace

I have an xml-base .tbx file containing code like this:

```
<descripGrp>
      <descrip type="subjectField">406001</descrip>
    </descripGrp>
    <langSet xml:lang="en">
      <tig>
        <term>competence of the Member States</term>
        <termNote type="termType">fullForm</termNote>
        <descrip type="reliabilityCode">3</descrip>
      </tig>
    </langSet>
    <langSet xml:lang="pl">
      <tig>
        <term>kompetencje państw członkowskich</term>
        <termNote type="termType">fullForm</termNote>
        <descrip type="reliabilityCode">3</descrip>
      </tig>
    </langSet>
  </termEntry>
  <termEntry id="IATE-290">
    <descripGrp>
      <descrip type="subjectField">406001</descrip>
    </descripGrp>
```

I want to search and replace within entire (almost 50 MiB) file for codes from the field "subjectField" and replace the with proper text, eg.
406001 is for Political ideology, 406002 for Political institution. 
I have a table with codes and corresponding names:
406001  Political ideology
406002  Political institution
406003  Political philosophy

There's five hundred of such codes so doing it by hand would take like forever.
I'm not a programmer (I'm learnig) but I know a little java so I made some little app which, I supposed, would help me, however the result is discouraging (luckily I'm not discouraged :))

That's what I wrote, the result is that it works extremely slow, doesn't replace those codes at all. It processed 1/5 of the file in 15 minutes (!). Additionally there are no new line characters in the output file so the entire xml code is in one line.

Any tips on which way I should go?

```
    File log= new File("D:\\IATE\\export_EN_PL_2017-03-07_All_Langs.tbx"); // TBX file to be processed
    File newe = new File("D:\\IATE\\now.txt"); // output file
    String search = "D:\\IATE\\org.txt"; // file containing codes "40600" etc
    String replace = "D:\\IATE\\rplc.txt"; // file containing names 

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(log);
        String s;
        String s1;
        String s2;
        String totalStr = "";
        String tot1 = "";
        String tot2 = "";
        FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(search);
        FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(replace);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            try (BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1)) {
                try (BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2)) {
                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        totalStr += s;
                            while((s1 = br1.readLine()) != null){
                                tot1 += s1;

                                while ((s2 = br2.readLine()) != null){
                                    tot2 += s2;
                                }
                            }
                        totalStr = totalStr.replaceAll(tot1, tot2);

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newe);

                    fw.write(totalStr);
                    fw.write("\n");
                    fw.close();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to be making way more readers than necessary. You said you have a table attributing codes to a corresponding name, what kind of file is that and how is it organized?

Comment: I have two files, in the first one there are numbers, codes: org.txt eg. 406003 and corresonding names in the other one: rplc.txt eg. Political ideology. It's like a two columns table divided into two files.

Comment: With Java you can run XSLT 2.0 at least using Saxon 9 (available from Maven and Sourceforge in the free HE) so I would consider doing this with XSLT 2.0. It is certainly not the right way to do that with string processing and simple file IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its going to take a lot of redundant work to traverse 2 files to get matching values. Before you replace values in the .tbx files you should set up a properties file to read from. Here's a function that would do that:

```
public static Properties getProps(String pathToNames, String pathToNumbers){

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try{
        File names = new File(pathToNames);
        BufferedReader theNames = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(names)));
        File numbers = new File(pathToNumbers);
        BufferedReader theNumbers = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(numbers)));

        String name;
        String number;
        while(((name = theNames.readLine())!= null)&&((number = theNumbers.readLine())!= null)){
            prop.put(number, name);
        }
        theNames.close();
        theNumbers.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prop;
}
```

Assuming you are using Java 8, you can check that the function is working with this:

```
thePropertiesFile.forEach((Object key, Object value) ->{
    System.out.println(key+ "  " +value);
});
```

Now you can write a function that will convert properly. Use a `PrintStream` to achieve the output functionality you want.

```
static String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
public static void main(String[] args){

    Properties p = getProps(workingDir+"path/to/names.txt",workingDir+"path/to/numbers.txt");
    File output = new File(workingDir+"path/to/output.txt");

    try {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(output);
        BufferedReader tbx = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(new File(workingDir+"path/to/the.tbx"))));
        String currentLine;
        String theNum;
        String theName;
        int c; //temp index
        int start;
        int end;
        while((currentLine = tbx.readLine()) != null){
            if(currentLine.contains("subjectField")){
                c = currentLine.indexOf("subjectField");
                start = currentLine.indexOf(">", c)+1;
                end = currentLine.indexOf("<", c);
                theNum = currentLine.substring(start, end);
                theName = p.getProperty(theNum);
                currentLine = currentLine.substring(0,start)+theName+currentLine.substring(end);
            }
            ps.println(currentLine);            
        }
        ps.close();
        tbx.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

For numbers that don't exist, this will replace them with a null string. You can update that for your specific use.

If theNum contains multiple values, split into an array:

```
theName = "";
if(theNum.contains(","){
  int[] theNums = theNum.split(",");     
  for (int num : theNums) {
      theName += p.getProperty(num);
      theName += ",";
  }
  theName = theName.replaceAll(",$", ""); //get rid of trailing comma
}
else
   theName = p.getProperty(theNum);
```

Comment: hank you very much Joe! Your attitude seems to be more efficient and smarter :) I didn't know PrintStream or Property (I thought about using HashMap.) classes and it made writing the file so easy. I have few questions though, as I want to understand how it works. Additionally that code doesn't cover all possibilities which occur in the tbx file. There are things like: "subjectField">3606003, 5211005, 5641</descrip> which give "null" (I know why, of course) - fields with two or more codes. I need to use one more condition statements I suppose.

Comment: Yes it would be one more condition, `theNum` would contain 3606003, 5211005, 5641 in that condition, so just check `if(theNum.contains(",")` then do the appropriate logic to seperate it into an array or something

Comment: Don't forget to check as answered if this helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for the "comma" issue resolution, however there should be type "String" instead of "int" - .split method is String type, isn't it? I've changed it to String (as well as "num" variable in 'for each' loop) and it's working but not exactly well.... It converts only the first occurence in the chain (eg. "Agriculture, null, null") - the remaining values changes to "null". Has it something to do with type? I cannot find the root cause of that.

Comment: ...and anticipating the obvious question - I've checked if the 'null' codes are present in the numbers.txt file - they are - those which I've checked at least.

Comment: ERRATA: No assistance needed - there was space after each comma "033, 4334, 43003" - that's why it couldn't found next codes in the Properties. That's all, thanks again Joe.